# hidden trade mark in android app

Tags: android, hidden, gestures

I want to make a hidden trademark in my android app, kinda like the one in the android OS when you keep tapping and the kitkat or lollipop screen comes up, but I want an image to show up while this image is not stored in drawables, where can I store the image or maybe store it as a byte[] ? I want to protect it from reverse engineering

Comment: If other people want your image, they can just take a screenshot of it after launching the app. Is it? While storing it as a byte array hard coded in is a way to achieve this, I am confused your intension of doing this.

Comment: sorry for not making my intentions clear, my app is for a company so if someone steals the app and wants to use it, I need some way to keep my trademark in the app in some hidden gesture, since it's a private app not a public one.

So in conclusion if someone wants to steal the app he can't remove my trademark from the drawables or even find it in the code while reverse engineering,

Comment: There is no way to keep an attacker from getting something out of your apk. You can make it difficult by putting it in a byte array like you said and minifying the code but a determined attacker could still get it.